# SharePoint 2010 Claims Auth/FBA - Reset password not working

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, forms-authentication, forgot-password, claims

I have a SP site with Claims Authentication and FBA setup. Dual auth Win/Forms is working perfectly.

I have a asp:PasswordRecovery control on app page.
It appears to lookup the account correctly - returning 'not found' messages if the username is not found. However, it fails to reset the password with the following execption:

```
Exception information: 
   Exception type: NotImplementedException   
   Exception message: The method or operation is not implemented.   


Thread information: 
Thread ID: 10 
Thread account name: SERVER01\SPS_Farm 
Is impersonating: False 
Stack trace:    at    Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimsAuthMembershipProvider.GetUser(String name, Boolean userIsOnline)  
at System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.GetUser(String username, Boolean userIsOnline, Boolean throwOnError)  
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.PasswordRecovery.AttemptSendPasswordUserNameView()  
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.PasswordRecovery.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)  
at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)  
at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)  
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Thanks in advance.

Update:
I added:
    enablePasswordReset="true"
to the app web.config AND the token-service web.config

Wrote some some code to do a manual test, and still got this when my code tried to 'reset' the password:
    This provider is not configured to allow password resets. To enable password reset, set     enablePasswordReset to "true" in the configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not help since you seem to be looking up the user properly... but if you aren't doing this I know you can run into not implemented issues:

Make sure to get an instance of the user using the appropriate Membership Provider.

e.g.

```
MembershipUser myUser = Membership.Providers["aspMembership"].GetUser(userName, false);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue ... my code was tryingt to user the 'claims provider' which does not seem to allow it. I had to add the membership provider and connection information to the SharePoint site web.config directly as well. (I didn't need it there to perform the login since that was going though claims.)